# C++ std::regex multiline syntax

Tags: c++, regex, c++11

I can't seem to get my regex working right. On a multiline text in ECMAScript this regular expression `begin\n([\s\S]*\nend)?` matches exactly what I need, and [I tested it here](http://www.regexpal.com/).

When I translate it into C++, it fails to match the same text.

Here is my code in Visual C++ 2010:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <regex>

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    std::regex metadataBlockRegex("begin\\n([\\s\\S]*\\nend)?",
        std::regex::ECMAScript);

    std::string text =
      "begin\n"
      "  123\n"
      "end\n";

    std::sregex_iterator blocksBegin(text.begin(), text.end(), metadataBlockRegex);
    std::sregex_iterator blocksEnd;

    for (auto blockMatch = blocksBegin; blockMatch != blocksEnd; ++blockMatch) {
            std::cout << (*blockMatch)[0].str();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

This outputs only "begin" and I expected it to match the whole text.

My question is: what is wrong here and where can I find a detailed description of `std::regex` engines' syntax and how they handle multiline strings.

Comment: This program prints the whole text (except for the last `\n`, which isn't matched) with clang++/libc++

Comment: This behaves as Gart describes in MSVC10.  The newline is not matched, and niether is anything after it.

Comment: Also prints the whole string with `boost::regex`

Comment: so, it looks like this is MSVC10 implementation-specific

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[LWG 2503](https://wg21.link/lwg2503) added the `multiline` syntax option, which should make your program work as expected when you use the option (for C++ implementations which support that new feature).

[LWG 2343](https://wg21.link/lwg2343) has some more background, which explains that ECMAScript RegExp objects have a Multiline property, which defaults to false, and the behaviour of different C++ `regex` implementations.

**Original answer from 2012:**

> what is wrong here

Not sure, it looks OK, but the only C++11 implementations I have access to don't support `<regex>`

> where can I find a detailed description of std::regex engines' syntax and how they handle multiline strings.

You can't, as far as I know.  The best place to look is probably the documentation for [Boost.Regex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/libs/regex/doc/html/index.html), but be aware that it's moved on since it was proposed for standardisation and has some features not present in `std::regex`.

Comment: Josuttis does have a description of how the different regex grammars differ. The behaviour you're seeing would be consistent with the egrep grammar, where \n separates alternate patters, so `begin` is a valid match for the first pattern. The ECMAScript grammar should not treat \n like that though.

Answer (score 5):

**No multiline support, anyway... not in MSVC10.**

You need to fake multiline with **\r & \n** in your patterns. It's a major bummer.